# Why won't these script tags work in my HTML file?

Tags: javascript, select, scope, this

I'm trying to create two dropdowns linked to two arrays and two buttons that initiate push/splice functions that trade items between the two drops downs.

I can't seem to get the javascript working. I first had it in a seperate file linked with src tags, but even putting it right in the html file won't work. Any advice?

## Here I am trying to learn more about javascript, and how to use it to control HTML.

```
<h2>Healthy Players</h2>
<div id = "healthyPlayers">
</div>
    <button type = "button" id = "injured" onlick = "starAthletes.athleteInjured()">Move to injured reserve.</button>


<h2>Injured Players</h2>
<div id = "injuredPlayers">
</div>
    <button type = "button" id "healthy" onclick = "starAthletes.athleteHealthy()">Move to team roster.</button>


<script>

    var starAthletes = {
        sports: ["Football", "Basketball", "Skateboarding", "Golf"],
        stars: [["Tom Brady", "Randy Moss"], ["Michael Jordan"], ["Tony Hawk"], ["Tiger Woods"]],
        injured: [[], [], [], []],


    listHealthyAthletes: function(){
        var healthyDropDown = "<select id = 'healthyDropDownList'>";
        for (var i = 0; i < this.sports.length; i++){
            healthyDropDown += "<optgroup label = '" + this.sports[i] + "'>";
            for (var j = 0; j < this.stars.length; j++){
                healthyDropDown += "<option>" + this.stars[i][j] + "</option>";    
            }
            healthyDropDown += "</optgroup>"
        }
        healthyDropDown += "</select>"
        document.getElementbyId("healthyDropDownList").innerHTML = healthyDropDown;
    },

    listInjuredAthletes: function(){
        var injuredDropDown = "<select id = 'injuredDropDownList'>";
        for (var i = 0; i < this.sports.length; i++){
            injuredDropDown += "<optgroup label = '" + this.sports[i] + "'>";
            for (var j = 0; j < this.stars[i].length; j++){
                injuredDropDown += "<option>" + this.stars[i][j] + "</option>";
            }
            injuredDropDown += "</optgroup>";
        }
        injuredDropDown += "</select>";
        document.getElementById("injuredDropDownList").innerHTML = injuredDropDown;
    },

    athleteInjured: function(){
        var selectedAthlete = document.getElementById("playerInjured").value;
        for(var i = 0; i < this.stars.length; i++){
            for(var j = 0; j < this.stars[i].length; j++){
                if (this.stars[i][j] == selectedAthlete){
                    alert(this.stars[i[j]] + "is currently on injured reserve.")
                    this.injured[i].push(this.stars[i].splice(j,1));
                }
            }
        } 
        this.listHealthyAthletes();
        this.listInjuredAthletes();
    },

    athleteHeathly: function(){
        var selectedAthlete = document.getElementById("playerHealthy").value;
        for(var i = 0; i < this.stars.length; i++){
            for(var j = 0; j < this.stars[i].length; j++){
                if (this.injured[i][j] == selectedAthlete){
                    alert(this.stars[i][j] + "is currently on the roster.")
                    this.stars[i].push(this.injured[i].splice(j,1));
                }
            }
        }
        this.listHealthyAlthetes();
        this.listInjuredAlthetes();
    }
    }
    starAthletes.listHealthyAthletes();
    starAthletes.listInjuredAthletes();

</script>
```

Comment: So, in `listHealthyAthletes()`, you have a call to `document.getElementbyId()` - rather than `document.getElementById()`. the case is significant (note `by` as opposed to `By`). Without seeing the complete code (in a https://repl.it/ or a https://jsfiddle.net for example), we can't really diagnose much more.

Comment: This is a great opportunity to start familiarizing yourself with JavaScript debugging tools.  Open your browser's development tools and check the console for errors.  Use the browser's script debugger to place breakpoints in your code to pause and observe the exact runtime behavior.  "It doesn't work" may be a true statement, but it's only the beginning of your diagnosis of the problem.

Comment: You have to initialize your drop down <select id="healthyDropDownList"></select>  in html (So tha DOM knows that what  healthyDropDownList or playerHealthy  is)   and add its option dynamically .The problem here is  your are selecting healthyDropDownList or playerHealthy even if they dont exists in DOM  and yes as @Snowmonkey there is a typo also